# Why does sendto() a Unix domain datagram socket (`socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)`) return EPERM?

Tags: linux, sockets, ipc, unix-socket

On a Linux 2.6.34 ppc system in a multi-process application under certain circumstances, `sendto()` between two PF_UNIX sockets returns -1 and `errno` `EPERM`. The only mention of `EPERM` in this context which I could find in the manual pages is in UNIX(7):

> `EPERM`  The sender passed invalid credentials in the *struct ucred*.

But this can't apply to `sendto()`, can it? Unfortunately, I couldn't put together a short, self-contained example to reproduce the problem yet. Here's an strace of the events:

```
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)          = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path=@"PIO "}, 11) = 0
...
sendto(3, "PIO \0\7\0\20\1\232\1\10\4\1\0\4\20\2\202\30\0\2\0\0", 24, MSG_DONTWAIT, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path=@"PWE7"}, 11) = 24
...
recv(3, "PAD \0#\0\2\3\347", 2008, 0)   = 10
recv(3, "PAD \0#\0\2\3\347", 2008, 0)   = 10
recv(3, "PAD \0#\0\2\3\347", 2008, 0)   = 10
recv(3, "DBUG\0(\0\n\1\250\0\3\0\1\0\1\0\1", 2008, 0) = 18
sendto(3, "PIO \0\3\0\30\1\303\0\3\0\1\0\1\0\1\0\1\20\2\202\34\0\2\0\0\0\2\0\0", 32, MSG_DONTWAIT, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path=@"DBUG"}, 11) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
recv(3, "PAD \0#\0\2\3\347", 2008, 0)   = 10
recv(3, "PAD \0#\0\2\3\347", 2008, 0)   = 10
recv(3, "PAD \0#\0\2\3\347", 2008, 0)   = 10
...
```

The process which gets the `EPERM` receives periodic messages `"PAD ..."` from one socket before and after it receives from another one a message `"DBUG..."` to which it shall respond using `sendto()`. Now, how can it be that this `sendto()` fails with `EPERM`, whereas other `sendto()`s (to other sockets) succeeded before?

Comment: Have you connect()'ed the socket ? (It appears you can get EPERM in the case of using a connected unix socket , either a dgram or stream socket, and the peer has died (and possibly re-created the socket).

Comment: No, `strace -e network` shows no `connect()`, only `socket()`, `bind()` and many `recv()` and `sendto()` calls. - I realize I should add to the question that other `sendto()`s succeed.

Comment: How is the socket created ? Can you strace anything that happens on the descriptor from the socket() call up till the failing sendto(). (multiple successful recv or sendto arn't that interresting, but any other calls are including bind(), fcntl, setsockopt or similar).

Comment: [There are at least a couple of places where it returns `EPERM`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/unix/af_unix.c#L1544).

Comment: @nos - I straced from the start. I'll include the `socket()` and `bind()` call in the question; the process makes no further network system calls.

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin - Indeed, there are two places, both `if (!unix_may_send(sk, other))`. Sadly I can neither find documentation of this condition nor figure out why and when exactly this occurs.

Comment: @Armali Yeah, I do not have enough free time to understand what `unix_may_send` checks for either.

Answer (score 1):

Update: the OP helped me understand that the below answer does NOT answer his question, since he is asking about `UNIX` domain sockets, created with `socket(PF_FILE, ..., ...)`, whatever that means :), and I am answering about `IP` sockets, created with `socket(AF_INET, ..., ...)`.

So, for UNIX domain sockets, this may not be relevant. And, **for `AF_INET` IP domain sockets, see this other Q&A now I just added here instead: [How to fix `EPERM` error when trying to use `sendto()` with Ethernet `socket(AF_INET, ..., ...)` (IP output packets) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74522604/4561887).**

Here is my relevant comment below this question:

> @Armali, you are correct. I am mistaken. Thanks for the clarification. I'll ask a new Q&A and move my answer when I get a chance. I was using `socket(AF_INET, ..., ...)`, similar to [this example I wrote here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c#L107), and mistakenly thought you had done the same. I didn't realize you are using `socket(PF_FILE, ..., ...)`. You're right. I don't know anything about that usage.

### How to fix `EPERM` (permissions error; 'E'rror 'PERM'issions) by disabling the firewall

After a ton of study, googling, testing on an embedded Linux board, etc, I've determined it's simply because you have a firewall up blocking your traffic. Do this to disable the firewall, then try again, and the `EPERM` error will go away:

```bash
# Manually disable the firewall
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t filter --flush
```

Comment: The question is about UNIX domain sockets, not IP.

Comment: @Armali, if you're talking about the Berkely sockets and the Unix/Linux [`sendto()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) function returning `EPERM` when you write C or C++ code calling that function, I am too. I can provide more details in my answer when I get a chance if it would be helpful. I feel like there's a lot more to say on the topic. It's pretty esoteric.

Comment: Correction: I mean the return value would be `-1` and `errno` would be set to `EPERM`. That's what I'm talking about. I have an embedded Linux board available I think that I can still cause to generate this behavior, and I may be able to go pull up some more details and output from things like `ping`, `nc`, `socat`, etc, and they are all related to EPERM, in addition to my own C++ code getting the EPERM error when `sendto()` is called. Disabling the firewall or opening connections through it properly fixed it.

Comment: @Armali, I know this question is super old. Would you prefer I opened up my own Q&A to cover my specific case? It's been 8 years. I doubt you remember anything about your original question.

Comment: If _you_ prefer, you can of course open up your own Q&A. I at least remember about my original question what I can read at the top of this page. When I am talking about UNIX domain sockets, I am talking about what is commonly known as UNIX domain sockets; you seem not aware of those local IPC sockets of address family _AF_UNIX_ or _PF_UNIX_ or _PF_FILE_, and they have nothing to do with firewalls or `ping`.

Comment: @Armali, you are correct. I am mistaken. Thanks for the clarification. I'll ask a new Q&A and move my answer when I get a chance. I was using `socket(AF_INET, ..., ...)`, similar to [this example I wrote here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_server_GS_edit_GREAT.c#L107), and mistakenly thought you had done the same. I didn't realize you are using `socket(PF_FILE, ..., ...)`. You're right. I don't know anything about that usage.

Comment: @Armali, I just moved my Q&A. See here: [How to fix `EPERM` error when trying to use `sendto()` with Ethernet `socket(AF_INET, ..., ...)` (IP output packets) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74522605/4561887)