# How to fix `EPERM` error when trying to use `sendto()` with Ethernet `socket(AF_INET, ..., ...)` (IP output packets) on Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ethernet, sendto

Here is a massively reduced code sample, following my code from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo here as a pattern: [socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_client_GS_edit_GREAT.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/socket__geeksforgeeks_udp_client_GS_edit_GREAT.c):

```c
#define SOCKET_TYPE_UDP_IPV4              AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0

// Create an IPv4 UDP socket to send Ethernet packets out to a connected device
int socket_fd = socket(SOCKET_TYPE_UDP_IPV4);

// Send a packet via `sendto()`
const char msg_to_send[] = "Hello from client.";
ssize_t num_bytes_sent = sendto(socket_fd, msg_to_send, sizeof(msg_to_send), 0,
    (const struct sockaddr *)&addr_server, sizeof(addr_server));
if (num_bytes_sent == -1)
{
    printf("Failed to send to server. errno = %i: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    goto cleanup;
}
```

`sendto()` fails, however, with the `num_bytes_sent` return code set to `-1` and `errno` set to `EPERM`. `EPERM` stands for "permissions error: 'E'rror 'PERM'issions". A list of all possible `errno` errors can be found here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html. It shows:

> `EPERM`  Operation not permitted (POSIX.1-2001).

However, **none** of the 3 reference pages I have for the `sendto()` function show `EPERM` as a valid or even *possible* error condition for calling this function! Here are the 3 reference pages I have for `sendto()`. See the "ERRORS" or "RETURN VALUE" section of each of them:

1. POSIX Programmer's Manual for `sendto()`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sendto.3p.html
2. man7.org "Linux Programmer's Manual" for `sendto()`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html
3. Linux.die.net manual for `sendto()`: https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto

So, what's happening and how do I fix it? I'd like `sendto()` to work so I can send out an Ethernet UDP packet to a connected device. On other machines it works fine, but from my embedded Linux board it fails with `EPERM`.

Answer (score 2):

### How to fix `EPERM` (permissions error; 'E'rror 'PERM'issions) by disabling the firewall

After a ton of study, googling, testing on an embedded Linux board, etc, I've determined it's simply because I have a firewall up blocking my outgoing traffic. Do this to disable the firewall, then try again, and the `EPERM` error will go away:

```bash
# Manually disable the firewall
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t filter --flush
```

One source that helped me conclude this was the problem, for instance, was Dmitry V. Krivenok here: [UDP socket && sendto && EPERM](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.protocols.tcp-ip/c/Qou9Sfgr77E/m/ZoEqk_7jZ1gJ) (emphasis added):

> The program works fine when I poll few hundred of devices,
> but I get strange error when I poll several thousand of devices:
>
> `sendto` returns `-1` with `errno` set to `EPERM` (Operation not permitted).
>
> `sendto` (2) manual page doesn't say anything about `EPERM`
> error.
>
> I searched through the google and found, that **`sendto` may**
> **fail with `errno` == `EPERM` if local firewall disallows outgoing UDP**
> **packets.**

### See also:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73302873/4561887
2. [Google search for "socket EPERM"](https://www.google.com/search?q=socket+EPERM&oq=socket+EPERM&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l2j69i60.2327j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
3. [Google search for "socket sendto EPERM"](https://www.google.com/search?q=socket+sendto+EPERM&oq=socket+sendto+EPERM&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l3.2623j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)